# ranger replace space in filenames

Tags: command-line, filemanager, remapping

I made map for moving file to Downloads directory but it cause problem if file has space

```
map dD console shell mv %s /home/${USER}/Downloads
```

Ofc I know that I can give their `""` but it will not work then for multiply files (what's important for me)
Is any other variable like %s what will replace `␣` -> `\␣`?
Or maybe I can resolve this somehow else

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot see this? https://i.imgur.com/01TsrtN.png

Comment: @sudodus `map` is part of the `ranger` configuration syntax. According to the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ranger.1) *"Macros for file paths are generally shell-escaped so they can be used in the "shell" command."* which implies it *should* work as-is. Is `console` strictly necessary here? I wonder if that's stripping one layer of shell escaping?

Comment: When  remove `console` it's work, I added it to need hit ENTER but it's cool, thanks!